# Weird error in Scipy Python

Tags: python, exception, scipy

I have a weird error in the following line of my code:

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(MyMatrix, 0.95, criterion='distance')
```

It is weird for several reasons:

- Error is arising randomly. Several executions of the same code will
  raise the error in 8 cases out of 10.
- When error arises in about 6 cases out of 8, python will not return any readable error, but instead Python process terminates with  the following message: `Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)` (exact code and pointer are variable, `-1073741819 (0xC0000005)` is frequent too)
- When error arises, it can appear as several different instances of errors (`ValueError: Linkage 'Z' contains negative counts.`, `Linkage 'Z' uses the same cluster twice`.)

Does anyone know where it could arise from and how it can be debugged?

Comment: does this happen for different matrices? Or only for one special? That would be the first thing I tried. And, if it happens for other data as well - can you provide a minimal working example to reproduce the error?

Comment: What is the size of  `MyMatrix`?

Comment: myMatrix is an numpy array of about 700x700. This happens for several matrices. I currently have a collection of about 70. This error has never arised the last time I touched the code (about a year ago) and the code has not been modified in between.

Comment: Ok, after 5 hours of debugging, it seems that it was a randomly arising `nan`. When it is supplied to the distance matrix in the `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(Distance matrix, method=centroid)`, in six cases out of 8 it will fail without any explicit error message and in the remaining passing the obtained linkage matrix will lead to fail the `fcluster` method. I will go ahead and fill a bug report with scipy.